# How to get Page assembly from a Control?

Tags: asp.net, controls, assemblies

I've create a method that gets the current page's assembly name and version so that I can display it in the page footer. It works just fine, but I'd like to move this logic into a control that I could drop into any web application project master page that references my control library. However, in the control library `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` returns the control library assembly, not the web project assembly.

Here's the method:

```
    private string GetVersion()
    {
        const string cacheKey = "Web.Controls.ApplicationVersion";
        string version = (string) Page.Cache[cacheKey];
        if (version == null)
        {
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

            // get the assembly version
            Version assemblyVersion = assembly.GetName().Version;

            // get the product name
            string productName;
            AssemblyProductAttribute productAttribute =
                assembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (AssemblyProductAttribute), false).Cast
                    <AssemblyProductAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (productAttribute != null)
            {
                productName = productAttribute.Product;
            }
            else
            {
                productName = String.Empty;
            }

            version = String.Format("{0} {1}", productName, assemblyVersion);

            Page.Cache[cacheKey] = version;
        }

        return version;
    }
```

I've also tried `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` which returns null, and `Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()` which returns the control assembly. Finally I tried `Assembly.GetAssembly(Page.GetType())`, which returns the page type generated at runtime (ASP.abc).

How can I get the web project assembly from within the context of a Control without asking for it explicitly by name?

Comment: For now I've added an ApplicationType property to the control that I use to create an instance of Type and get the assembly with `Assembly.GetAssembly(type)`. Its not ideal, but it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe it is not in time. But today I had run into the same issue. And first  what I had found was your questions without answer ( . Later I digged around this question.
The answer is: `Assembly.GetAssembly(Page.GetType().BaseType)`

The reason is generation page type at runtime as you mentioned above.
Good explanation I found in MSDN:

> The type of the HTTP handler for a particular page depends on the URL.
>   The first time the URL is invoked, a new class is composed and
>   dynamically compiled to an assembly. The source code of the class is
>   the outcome of a parsing process that examines the .aspx sources. The
>   class is defined as part of the namespace ASP and is given a name that
>   mimics the original URL. For example, if the URL endpoint is
>   page.aspx, the name of the class is ASP.Page_aspx. The class name,
>   though, can be programmatically controlled by setting the ClassName
>   attribute in the @Page directive.
>
> The base class for the HTTP handler is Page. This class defines the
>   minimum set of methods and properties shared by all page handlers. The
>   Page class implements the IHttpHandler interface.
>
> Under a couple of circumstances, the base class for the actual handler
>   is not Page but a different class. This happens, for example, if
>   code-behind is used. Code-behind is a development technique that
>   insulates the code necessary to a page into a separate C# or Microsoft
>   Visual Basic® .NET class. The code of a page is the set of event
>   handlers and helper methods that actually create the behavior of the
>   page. This code can be defined inline using the 
>   tag or placed in an external class—the code-behind class. A
>   code-behind class is a class that inherits from Page and specializes
>   it with extra methods. When specified, the code-behind class is used
>   as the base class for the HTTP handler.

So when you are using `Page.GetType()` you will get dynamic composed class. And this class is inherited from actual page class, and this one is into project assembly.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479007.aspx -MSDN article refference.